# Best strategy to solve a small nonlinear optimization problem with nonlinear constraints?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I have the following problem:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\max_{x\in\mathbb{R}^2}f(x) \\
\text{s.t. }&c(x)\ge 0 \\
& x_{l,i} \le x_i \le x_{u,i}, i=1,2
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Both the gradient and the Hessian for both $f$ and $c$ are available as closed form expressions (they are at least twice differentiable).

**What would be a robust and fast strategy for solving this problem?**

Here, $f$ is actually not necessarily convex but I was planning on using a low-discrepancy sequence for sampling initial conditions (filtering out starting points that would violate the constraint) and repeat the procedure. I don't expect more than 2 or 3 local optima.

Scipy's wrapper for Dieter Kraft's SLSQP code works excellent, but I want to write my own code from scratch. Also, I don't need any BFGS estimates of the Hessian(s) since I already have them.

I think Algorithm 18.3 (Line search SQP) in Numerical Optimization by Nocedal & Wright would work as long as $\nabla^2\mathcal{L}_k$ would remain positive definite on the null space of the equality constraints, but what would be reasonable way of modifying it accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went for [Locally Feasibly Projected Sequential Quadratic Programming](https://arxiv.org/abs/2111.03236). Closing.

Answer (score 1):

My best strategy preference (that would make me believe that I am, at least, close to the best answer) is to first proceed with a random Monte Carlo sampling in this two dimensional space.

Take the best found pair, in accord with the constraints, and proceed to employ a gradient method in two dimensions to possibly improve upon the result. Even if this produces only a minor improvement, stop and record the new estimates.

Repeat again with the Monte Carlo random sampling and see if you get any further improvements. If yes, record results.

Continue to repeat this process until you reach a level of confidence in your best final estimates.

Note, this methodology works best with a quick efficient gradient method. I cite the work of Bin Zhou: ['Gradient Methods with Adaptive Step-Sizes'](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Yu-Hong-Dai/publication/225728940_Gradient_Methods_with_Adaptive_Step-Sizes/links/0deec51c9a3549e923000000/Gradient-Methods-with-Adaptive-Step-Sizes.pdf), to quote from the abstract:

> Motivated by the superlinear behavior of the Barzilai-Borwein (BB) method for two-dimensional quadratics, we propose two gradient methods which adaptively choose a small step-size or a large step-size at each iteration. The small step-size is primarily used to induce a favorable descent direction for the next iteration, while the large step-size is primarily used to produce a sufficient reduction. Although the new algorithms are still linearly convergent in the quadratic case, numerical experiments on some typical test problems indicate that they compare favorably with the BB method and some other efficient gradient methods.

I hope this helps.